# my code has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: c

This is the original problem :  ""A class of ten students took a quiz. The grades for this
quiz are available to you. Determine the class average on the quiz""

```
int main(){
float average, total, currentnote, i;
average,total = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("please enter the quiz result:");
    scanf_s("%d", &currentnote);
    total = total + currentnote;
        if (i = 9){
        average = total / 10;
        printf("result equals= %f", average);
        getchar();

       }
    }
}
```

After I enter one number it exits with error

```
  The program '[3272] Project1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Can someone show me my error?

Comment: `if (i = 9)` isn't going to test equality!

Comment: "exited with code 0" doesn't imply an error.  Your program will still do that even with the logical error fixed.

Comment: a zero exit code _should_ be good news, even though you have some issues you need do address in your code

Comment: Kind of surprising that no one pointed out the *other* problem with `i = 9`: `i` is `float` and exact comparisons often fail with floating point numbers. I would be very hesitant to use a floating point number for loop control under *any* circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides having to test for equality as `if (i == 9)`,

you can't set two variables equal to a common value this way: `average, total = 0`

Do `average = total = 0` instead.

The `currentnote` variable is a float - but your format flag for `scanf_s` is telling it to expect an `int`.

For clarity of intention in the code, why is this inside the `for` loop?  Why not put it after the `for` loop?

```
  if (i == 9){
  average = total / 10;
  printf("result equals= %f", average);
  getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (i = 9)
```

Should be

```
if (i == 9)
```

See if that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
scanf_s("%d"....
```

But `%d` is for `ints`, and you have a `float`.
**Use `%f`.**